# Mirror Symmetry References

Tags: algebraic-geometry, mirror-symmetry

For someone comfortable with Hartshorne's book chapters 2 and 3 which references would be good to learn mirror symmetry (specially the homological flavor), GW invariants and related problems? I intend to start learning in a slow pace to try to keep up with the area when I finish my PhD.

Comment: I believe you mean intend, rather than pretend.